# CentOS Service Reboot Issue

Tags: centos

I am recently learning about linux (Cent OS) and i came across to a weird problem. I am going through a chapter "Managing Services" and in the book its written to restart a network i should use the below command

**/etc/init.d/network restart**

But when i am using the above command nothing is happening. Instead when i use this command "**/etc/init.d/service network restart**", i am able to restart. Could anyone explain what is the difference ????

Comment: `ls -la /etc/init.d/network` what is the output ? in CentOS you should be able to call any service using `service service_name command` (you don't actually need the `/etc/init.d/`) service is merelly an agent that will simplify your services commands. Also are you using a remote user to get to root or physical access ? if you are using a user make sure you are moving to root with the follow command `su -` or `su - root`

Comment: @Prix - using sudo i the better way to go instead of escalating to a full root shell.

Comment: The output of ls -la /etc/init.d/network is -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8257 Jul 4 2009 /etc/init.d/network and yes i did tried sudo but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not root when you're running `/etc/init.d/network restart`. It should work the same as `service network restart` (note that service is not prefixed with `/etc/init.d`).

Comment: I am the root user...

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/messages` after you run the command? That's very strange that you see no output whatsoever.